# .net maui add objects to canvas on runtime

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

Lets say I have very simple `xaml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:drawable="clr-namespace:eden.Pages"
             x:Class="eden.Pages.Modeler">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
    <drawable:GraphicsDrawable x:Key="drawable" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <GraphicsView x:Name="modelerArea"
            Drawable="{StaticResource drawable}">
            <FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
                <MenuFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Add rectangle"
                            Clicked="AddRectangle"> <!-- HERE I WANT TO ADD RECTANGLE ON CLICK -->
                    </MenuFlyoutItem>
                </MenuFlyout>
            </FlyoutBase.ContextFlyout>
        </GraphicsView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And then very simple `xaml.cs`

```
public partial class Modeler : ContentPage
    {
        public Modeler()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddRectangle(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // for example
           // var mySpecialRectangle = new specialRectangle();
           // canvas.Add(mySpecialRectangle);
        }
    }

    public class GraphicsDrawable : IDrawable
    {
        public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
        {
            canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
            canvas.StrokeSize = 6;
            canvas.DrawLine(10, 10, 90, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I add that object to canvas/graphicsview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rectangle is drawing in the graphicsview. So you can create a class inherited from the `IDrawable` and then set it as the `Drawable` property of the instance of the `GraphicsView`. Finally, you can add the instance of the `GraphicsView` into the layout. Such as:

In the page.xaml:

```
<VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
        x:Name="layout">
        <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

In the page.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

      public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }
    internal class RectangleDrawable : IDrawable
    {
        public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
        {
            canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.DarkBlue;
            canvas.StrokeSize = 4;
            canvas.DrawRectangle(10, 10, 100, 50);
        }
    }
    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            
            GraphicsView graphicsView = new GraphicsView();
            graphicsView.Drawable = new RectangleDrawable();
        graphicsView.HeightRequest= 200;
        graphicsView.WidthRequest = 400;
        layout.Children.Add(graphicsView);
      }
}
```

The Rectangle will be drawn when you clicked the button.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Actually if I am right this will add another graphicsview in to layout? I want to add more elements on one graphics view.

Comment: But the `graphicsView.Drawable` can just set one drawable. @JurajJakubov

Comment: Oh i see. And is there any way how can i add more elements to one canvas on click for example. Like I click and it will add new line or someting but to the same canvas.

Comment: It seems there is no a such api for the `graphicsView`. Or you can try to use the SKCanvas in the maui. The [SkiaSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/drawing) package has supported the maui.@JurajJakubov

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [Draw graphical objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/draw?view=net-maui-7.0)?

You don't "add objects" in the `ICanvas` approach. Rather, you make "draw" calls.

`modelerArea` is `canvas` in your `xaml`, so it will be variations on:

```cs
public void MyDrawLine(ICanvas canvas, ...)
{
    canvas.DrawLine(...);
}

...
MyDrawLine(modelerArea, ...);
```

Caveat: I've never done this myself; I'm basing this on the linked doc.

An implication is that if you want to "remember" some "objects" for later, you'll have to do that yourself. Define your own class that describes an object to draw. Maintain a list of those object "models", so you can draw them all later.